# Missing libappindicator1

Tags: apt, package-management, kali-linux

So I wanted to install Google Chrome on My Kali Linux Distro and it appeared that I miss `libappindicator1` which Chrome is dependent of. So I tried to install the package and it says:

```
Package libappindicator1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'libappindicator1' has no installation candidate
```

I entered the following command:

```
apt-cache search libappindcator1
```

But got no response. Coming to conclusion that the package isn't even there.

How do I install it?

Additional info: The contents of my `sources.list` in `/etc/apt`:

```
deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.0 _Kali_ - Official Snapshot i386
LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20150312-18:43]/ kali contrib main non-free

deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.0 _Kali_ - Official Snapshot i386
LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20150312-18:43]/ kali contrib main non-free

deb http://security.kali.org/ kali/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.kali.org/ kali/updates main contrib non-free
```

Comment: Can you edit you question with your /etc/apt/sources.list ?

Comment: I will, Let me boot into kali

Comment: I think you shoud add kali offical repositories: [http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories](http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories) and then apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get dist-upgrade -y.

Answer (score 6):

After getting that error, run command:

```
apt-get -f install
```

And it installs.. why? I don't know.

https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?22243-Google-chrome-not-installing-properly/page2

Comment: What is this sorcery?! It works but I really want to know why..

Comment: From man page: `-f Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place. This option, when used with install/remove, can omit any packages to permit APT to deduce a likely solution.` fwiw I ran it but it did not do the trick for me. All it told me was the before-seen `The following programs were automatically installed and are no longer required` message. Ran `apt autoremove` as suggested. Re-ran my 1Password Linux installer (the thing/activity that is requiring `libappindicator1`) and it failed again. Now looking at `Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages`...

Comment: This worked for me in a related situation.  I was trying to install `Whatever` (which is a desktop Evernote client for linux) on a LMDE 5 system (i.e. Linux Mint distro based on Debian bullseye).

Answer (score 3):

I ended up here trying to install Signal, here's what worked for me:

Package was removed from Kali [repositories](http://pkg.kali.org/pkg/libappindicator#)
You will need to manually install the missing packages.
First check your CPU architecture to find out what binary you'll need

```
$ lscpu | grep Architecture
Architecture:                    x86_64
```

So for my case it's amd64, you can find other versions there too.
https://pkgs.org/download/libappindicator1
https://pkgs.org/download/libindicator7

```
curl -p --insecure "http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/liba/libappindicator/libappindicator1_0.4.92-8_amd64.deb" --output libappindicator1_0.4.92-8_amd64.deb
curl -p --insecure "http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libi/libindicator/libindicator7_0.5.0-4_amd64.deb" --output libindicator7_0.5.0-4_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg --install libindicator7_0.5.0-4_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install libdbusmenu-gtk4
sudo dpkg --install libappindicator1_0.4.92-8_amd64.deb
```

Then you should be able to follow the steps on the Signal wiki.

Comment: Thanks, I was having dependency issue with libappindicator1 while installing Discord on my Kali Linux 2021.2. Your way helps me a lot.

Comment: solved same way on debian. ```curl -p --insecure "http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/liba/libappindicator/libappindicator1_0.4.92-7_amd64.deb" --output libappindicator1_0.4.92-8_amd64.deb \
    && curl -p --insecure "http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libi/libindicator/libindicator7_0.5.0-4_amd64.deb" --output libindicator7_0.5.0-4_amd64.deb \
    && dpkg -i libindicator7_0.5.0-4_amd64.deb \
    && dpkg -i libappindicator1_0.4.92-8_amd64.deb \
    && rm libindicator7_0.5.0-4_amd64.deb \
    && rm libappindicator1_0.4.92-8_amd64.deb```

Answer (score 0):

While installing google-chrome, I also faced related error message.

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
google-chrome-stable depends on libappindicator1; however:
Package libappindicator1 is not installed.
```

So, next I tried installing libappindicator1, which again gave me the following message :

```
root@Am-I-Helpful:~/Downloads# apt-get install libappindicator1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libappindicator1 : Depends: libdbusmenu-glib4 (>= 0.4.2) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libdbusmenu-gtk4 (>= 0.4.2) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libindicator7 (>= 0.4.90) but it is not going to be installed
                    Recommends: indicator-application (>= 0.2.93) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

It asked me to fire `apt-get -f install` to carry on the installation. So, I proceeded with the  command :

```
root@Am-I-Helpful:~/Downloads# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libappindicator1 libdbusmenu-glib4 libdbusmenu-gtk4 libindicator7
Recommended packages:
  indicator-application
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libappindicator1 libdbusmenu-glib4 libdbusmenu-gtk4 libindicator7
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 299 kB of archives.
After this operation, 638 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali sana/main amd64 libdbusmenu-glib4 amd64 12.10.2-1 [104 kB]
Get:2 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali sana/main amd64 libdbusmenu-gtk4 amd64 12.10.2-1 [90.8 kB]
Get:3 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali sana/main amd64 libindicator7 amd64 0.5.0-2 [52.2 kB]
Get:4 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali sana/main amd64 libappindicator1 amd64 0.4.92-3.1 [52.5 kB]
Fetched 299 kB in 13s (21.8 kB/s)          
Selecting previously unselected package libdbusmenu-glib4:amd64.
(Reading database ... 295344 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libdbusmenu-glib4_12.10.2-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdbusmenu-glib4:amd64 (12.10.2-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdbusmenu-gtk4:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libdbusmenu-gtk4_12.10.2-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdbusmenu-gtk4:amd64 (12.10.2-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libindicator7.
Preparing to unpack .../libindicator7_0.5.0-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libindicator7 (0.5.0-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libappindicator1.
Preparing to unpack .../libappindicator1_0.4.92-3.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libappindicator1 (0.4.92-3.1) ...
Setting up libdbusmenu-glib4:amd64 (12.10.2-1) ...
Setting up libdbusmenu-gtk4:amd64 (12.10.2-1) ...
Setting up libindicator7 (0.5.0-2) ...
Setting up libappindicator1 (0.4.92-3.1) ...
Setting up google-chrome-stable (52.0.2743.116-1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable to provide /usr/bin/x-www-browser (x-www-browser) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable to provide /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser (gnome-www-browser) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable to provide /usr/bin/google-chrome (google-chrome) in auto mode
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.21-6) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.47) ...
```

After this, I was successfully able to install google-chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. `apt-get -f install` wasn't enough to get all the dependencies resolved for the Vivaldi .deb file I downloaded. (I recently upgraded to Debian 9 and have had problems installing various things--not sure why yet.) I ended up doing this instead...

From https://gist.github.com/pkorpine/16fcdbe070222cf1d99e67cf542e60c2

```
echo "deb http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list > /dev/null

wget -O - http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt update && sudo apt install vivaldi-stable
```

Answer (score 0):

By running the command `sudo apt-get -f install` it fix my problem.
`-f` mean `--fix-broken`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. sometimes apt fails to find things.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62903826/1487110

I do know the problem was with apt becausue I had already installed the app before I started getting software updater errors. So I focused on that.

Context: In my case I ALSO had this error

```
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/source/Sources' as repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

And many more like that one.

Of course, make sure to backup those files.

Answer (score -3):

You can use the following to ignore the missing dependency:

```
dpkg --configure -a --force-depends
```