# Unmet dependencies libappindicator1

Tags: linux, linux-mint, apt, dependencies

I am trying to install the VPN client Forticlient on my Linux Mint distribution, but it can't install it because of this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 forticlient : Depends: libappindicator1 (> 0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

It looks like this libappindicator1 is missing so I researched the problem, for example here: [Missing libappindicator1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191551/missing-libappindicator1), where the solution is:

```
apt-get -f install
```

This does not solve my problem. I try to install libappindicator1 directly using aptitude and I get this error:

> libappindicator1 : Depends: libindicator7 (>= 0.4.90) which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

I cant find out how to resolve this anywhere, or how to get this libindicator7 module - I'm not sure what it means it is a virtual package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like Linux Mint developers for some reason dropped `libindicator7` package from official repositories. One solution could be to [download](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libindicator7#pdownload) this package from, for example, [Debian repository](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libindicator7), and install it with:

```
dpkg -i libindicator7_0.5.0-3+b1_amd64.deb
```

Just make sure you download and install the package for the correct CPU architecture.

Finally, run this command to fix your dependency tree:

```
apt-get -f install
```

Comment: Worked beautifully, thanks a lot

Comment: This answer didn't work for me on LMDE 5. If you have the same issue, come check the separate post I created: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/723131/installing-forticlient-vpn-on-debian-bullseye-version-of-libappindicator1-on-sy/723138#723138